# MDM commands and payloads

Tags: mdm

Where can I obtain the complete MDM commands and payloads used in iOS? I've been searching in Google for a week now, and I got an older list of commands (written in 2012).

Answer (score 0):

Members of the Apple Developer Enterprise Program can get it. It is not publicly available.